# PowerBuilder 11.5 SccMaxArraySize does not work with TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, powerbuilder

I have a problem with TFS 2010 and PowerBuilder 11.5 (mediated by [TFS 2010 MSSCCI provider 32-bit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2010MSSCC)). When I try to "Add to source control" the whole target or pbl with more than 25 objects then changesets are **limited to 25 files**, so I have to click "Check in" many times until all objects are added to TFS.

I tried to add the option [SccMaxArraySize](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charles_sterling/2006/11/30/using-the-tfs-mssci-provider-with-powerbuilder-only-checking-in-25-files-per-changeset/) in pb.ini file's [Library] section but that did not help even after PC was restarted.

Any ideas how to overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of TFS MSSCCI provider do you use? Do you use TFS 2013 & 2015 MSSCCI Provider 32-bit version?

Comment: I do not use TFS but I found this article and hope it helps: http://www.zeusedit.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=7486

Comment: @Arthoor, do you have other machines to test this setting? I'm not able to find a PowerBuilder 11.5 download to test your scenario.

Comment: @EduardoG. Thank you, but that article tells exactly the same thing about SccMaxArraySize that I've already tried - it does not work for me, this is what all my question is about.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, yes, we've tested it on another machine with the same results.

Comment: As TFS doesn't have such limitation, I'm afraid you need get support from PowerBuilder side. But if you could provide a PowerBuilder 11.5 download, I would like to have a test with my TFS 2015 to see whether it works or not.